# MVC.ASP.NET and problem with route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Now I have to fix some bugs in MVC.Asp.Net project. In projec i have route:

Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Category no name",
    "_C{id}.cfm",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Category" },
    new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Category(int id)
{
        // Break point here
        // doing smth
    return View();
}
```

In view I have link:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Category", "Products", new { id = category.CategoryId })">@category.Name</a>
```

Everything is working correct when I use Visual Studio Development Server but when I try to run project on Local IIS server ( I use http://localhost/TestSite) I have problem with this link. It doesn't work and I can't fall to break point in my controller.

Why do I have this behaviour? May be smth wrong with my link? I can't change route in global.asax.

Thanks, for any ideas

Comment: are you using IIS (5/6). if so, please check with this URLs http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx and http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that the IIS is not configured properly. Try to set integrated mode for the IIS pool. Or map .cfm extension to ASP .NET.

Comment: Thanks, I set application pool = ASP.NET v4.0 and this have solved my problems